# my site drop down menu is not working ( with a messy menu )

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

I started to make my website (to learn html, css and java script better) but I had a problem (dropdown menu not working and menu display not good) (menu doesn't want not display submenus) and I don't know why the animation of the dropdown menu does not work . please some help to make it appear and adjust the menu display .

here are the codes :

```js
/* Fonction pour faire apparaître le sous-menu */
function showSubmenu() {
  document.getElementById("submenu").classList.add("submenu-open");
}

/* Fonction pour faire disparaître le sous-menu */
function hideSubmenu() {
  document.getElementById("submenu").classList.remove("submenu-open");
}

/* Fonction pour ajouter les événements de survol sur le menu */
function addMenuEvents() {
  var menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item");
  for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
    menuItems[i].addEventListener("mouseover", showSubmenu);
    menuItems[i].addEventListener("mouseout", hideSubmenu);
  }

  // Ajout de l'événement click pour le lien "Produits"
  var productsLink = document.querySelector(".menu-item[href='#']");
  productsLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleSubmenu();
  });
}

/* Appel de la fonction pour ajouter les événements de survol sur le menu */
addMenuEvents();

/* Fonction pour basculer l'état d'affichage du sous-menu */
function toggleSubmenu() {
  var submenu = document.getElementById("submenu");
  submenu.classList.toggle("submenu-open");
}
/* Fonction pour faire disparaître le sous-menu */
function hideSubmenu() {
  document.getElementById("submenu").classList.remove("submenu-open");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}


/* Style du menu */

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgb(143, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/* Style des éléments du menu */

.menu-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Style des éléments du menu au survol */

.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Style du sous-menu */

.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/* Style des éléments du sous-menu */

.submenu-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Style des éléments du sous-menu au survol */

.submenu-item:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Ajouter une classe pour afficher le sous-menu avec l'animation */

.submenu-open {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
}


/* Style de la barre de navigation */

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #8B0000, #FFA500);
  ;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style du conteneur de recherche */

.search-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Style du champ de recherche */

.search-container input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
}


/* Style du bouton de recherche */

.search-container button {
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}


/* Style des icônes */

.icon-link {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.fa-user,
.fa-shopping-cart {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Rendre les icônes rouges */
}

.search-container input[type=text] {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.search-container button {
  padding: 12px;
  border: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.fa-search {
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* Ajouter cette propriété pour rendre l'icône de recherche arrondi */
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}


/* Style du sous-menu */

.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Ajouter une opacité initiale de 0 pour cacher le sous-menu */
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  /* Ajouter une translation initiale de -10px pour déplacer le sous-menu vers le haut */
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  /* Ajouter une transition de 0,2 seconde avec un effet de fondu et de translation vers le haut */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

<header>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="search-container">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Rechercher...">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="icons-container">
      <a href="#" class="icon-link"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="icon-link"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-item" onmouseover="showSubmenu()">Produits</a>
          <ul class="submenu" id="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Produit 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Produit 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Produit 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  Please narrow the problem to a [mcve] (focus on *minimal* in this case) and specifically indicate what isn't working as expected in that example.  Is a specific JavaScript operation not working as expected?  A specific CSS style rule?  Something else?  Please clarify.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: "I asked chatgpt to solve the problem" — ChatGPT is a next-word-prediction engine. It is extremely bad at presenting facts or solving problems. Learn from a real tutorial written by a human.

Comment: You should take a careful look at the [ChatGPT policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) for this site.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I think the ChatGPT rules are about answers, not about questions, right?

Comment: @MoritzRingler - The policy bans questions or answers generated by ChatGPT. This particular question is a bit gray-area: ChatGPT-generated code, followed by the OP having issues with it and asking people to help figure out what's wrong (which is also off-topic - it's "this doesn't work, please help me debug"). I posted the link for the OP to make sure they're not violating the rules. I didn't flag this (like I said... gray area) but...

Comment: @DavidMakogon Ah, interesting, I read the question as "I asked ChatGPT to help me write the code", not "I had ChatGPT write the code and now I don't know what to do". I guess that would make the difference.

Comment: @FaresDisusa Ah, now they closed your question, SO can be harsh that way. Don't worry about it. If it helps you, I think the issue was the amount of code you posted and that you didn't explain the issue clear enough. It would have sufficed to post just the code for the button and the menu and say "I hover over it, but I don't see the menu". Oh, and don't mention ChatGPT... You can shorten the question and apply to reopen it (which might work or bring more frustration). I can also delete my answer, I think then you can delete the question if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are two issues with your CSS:

1. the styles in `.submenu-open` are overridden by `.submenu`, so hovering over the button just adds a class with disabled properties

You can fix this by giving higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to the styles currently in `.submenu-open`, for example by combining the two classes into `.submenu.submenu-open`.

2. the submenu is positioned at the same position as the trigger, causing the menu to rapidly open and close because you are hovering the button which opens the menu, at which point you are not hovering the button and it closes leaving you to hover the button again and the cycle starts again.

The easy fix is to keep the menu open when you hover over it as well, not just the button. You might also want to move it a bit.

This would leave you with:

```css
.submenu.submenu-open, .submenu:hover {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 104px;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet:

```js
/* Fonction pour faire apparaître le sous-menu */
function showSubmenu() {
  document.getElementById("submenu").classList.add("submenu-open");
}

/* Fonction pour faire disparaître le sous-menu */
function hideSubmenu() {
  document.getElementById("submenu").classList.remove("submenu-open");
}

/* Fonction pour ajouter les événements de survol sur le menu */
function addMenuEvents() {
  var menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item");
  for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
    menuItems[i].addEventListener("mouseover", showSubmenu);
    menuItems[i].addEventListener("mouseout", hideSubmenu);
  }

  // Ajout de l'événement click pour le lien "Produits"
  var productsLink = document.querySelector(".menu-item[href='#']");
  productsLink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleSubmenu();
  });
}

/* Appel de la fonction pour ajouter les événements de survol sur le menu */
addMenuEvents();

/* Fonction pour basculer l'état d'affichage du sous-menu */
function toggleSubmenu() {
  var submenu = document.getElementById("submenu");
  submenu.classList.toggle("submenu-open");
}
/* Fonction pour faire disparaître le sous-menu */
function hideSubmenu() {
  document.getElementById("submenu").classList.remove("submenu-open");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}


/* Style du menu */

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgb(143, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/* Style des éléments du menu */

.menu-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Style des éléments du menu au survol */

.menu-item:hover {
  background-color: #333;
}


/* Style du sous-menu */

.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/* Style des éléments du sous-menu */

.submenu-item {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Style des éléments du sous-menu au survol */

.submenu-item:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Ajouter une classe pour afficher le sous-menu avec l'animation */

.submenu.submenu-open, .submenu:hover {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 104px;
}


/* Style de la barre de navigation */

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #8B0000, #FFA500);
  ;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* Style du conteneur de recherche */

.search-container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


/* Style du champ de recherche */

.search-container input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
}


/* Style du bouton de recherche */

.search-container button {
  padding: 6px;
  border: none;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}


/* Style des icônes */

.icon-link {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.fa-user,
.fa-shopping-cart {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Rendre les icônes rouges */
}

.search-container input[type=text] {
  width: 400px;
  padding: 12px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.search-container button {
  padding: 12px;
  border: none;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

.fa-search {
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* Ajouter cette propriété pour rendre l'icône de recherche arrondi */
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}


/* Style du sous-menu */

.submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Ajouter une opacité initiale de 0 pour cacher le sous-menu */
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  /* Ajouter une translation initiale de -10px pour déplacer le sous-menu vers le haut */
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in-out, transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  /* Ajouter une transition de 0,2 seconde avec un effet de fondu et de translation vers le haut */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">

<header>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="search-container">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Rechercher...">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="icons-container">
      <a href="#" class="icon-link"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a>
      <a href="#" class="icon-link"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-item" onmouseover="showSubmenu()">Produits</a>
          <ul class="submenu" id="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Produit 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Produit 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Produit 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```